# Texlive - restoring texlive/updmap font state?

Tags: texlive

Well, I just wanted to have `times` render in a DVI in `evince`; that command failed at `mktexpk`, basically something like this if I try to run it standalone:

```
$ TEXMFCNF=/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf/web2c  mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+60/600 --dpi 660 ptmri7t
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ptmri7t.
mktexpk: perhaps ptmri7t is missing from the map file.
```

Then I tried to `updmap --enable Map times.map`, then times.map doesn't exist `:(`.. then `updmap --disable times.map`, then `updmap --enable Map adobe.map`, than that didn't do anything, so I did `updmap --disable times.map`; then the same with `updmap-sys`... Apparently I've pasted also `updmap-sys --enable Map fourier.map`, so I disabled that too `updmap-sys --disable fourier.map` - and now, I'm at a point where pdflatex started spitting this out:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /home/USER/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts
/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): ambiguous entry for `zpcp32bc': font file prese
nt but not included, will be treated as font file not present


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /home/USER/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts
/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): ambiguous entry for `zpcp33bc': font file prese
nt but not included, will be treated as font file not present


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /home/USER/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts
/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): ambiguous entry for `zpcp33bc': font file prese
nt but not included, will be treated as font file not present
```

I tried also `updmap-sys --force --syncwithtrees` (and `updmap --force --syncwithtrees`) after any additions are seemingly removed, but no dice...

Any idea how I can "reset" everything back to defaults? Can one use `tlmgr` maybe? I'm on Ubuntu with Texlive 2011..

---

EDIT: solved my problem, my notes are below - but I think it's good to know if there's a "factory reset" for these kinds of things...

It turns out I forgot a `updmap --disable adobe.map`, now those warnings I gone  ... I just went through the log file, and saw that it has:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /home/USER/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts
/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): invalid entry for `@c': both ps_name and font file missing

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /home/USER/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts
/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): ambiguous entry for `@c': font file present but
 not included, will be treated as font file not present
```

... and then in the mentioned `pdftex.map`, I could see stuff like `@c " Adobe Type Basics " A 902` - which should apparently be comments, but seemingly aren't treated as such.

Comment: On miktex I would run `updmap --verbose >updmap.log` and `updmap --verbose --admin>updmap2.log` (`--admin is the miktex equivalent of updmap-sys`). And then I would check in the log-files which .cfg are used and which map-files are written and sort things out in an editor.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip, @UlrikeFischer - cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On miktex I would run `updmap --verbose >updmap.log` and `updmap --verbose --admin>updmap2.log` (`--admin` is the miktex equivalent of `updmap-sys`). And then I would check in the log-files which .cfg are used and which map-files are written and sort things out in an editor.